# multiple list comprehension Haskell

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension

I am trying to concat two lists with zipWith (++) but I get an error because list list1 is [[String]] and list list2 is [[Char]].

```
   temp (n:ns) = n : temp (ns)
   list1 = [ take 10 (repeat (show(n))) | n <- temp ['AA'..]]  
   list2 = infinite list of ['word'...]
```

EXAMPLE of list1 = `[['AA', 'AA', 'AA'..], ['BB', 'BB'..]]`

EXAMPLE of list2 = `['Word', 'Other', 'Diff', 'New']`

How can I combine A with B so that each item of A is applied to B1, then B2, ...?
So it should be `['WordAA', 'OtherAA'..], ['WordBB', 'OtherBB'..]`

Comment: What is `temp` doing here? It looks like this simply returns the same list. `'AA'` is also invalid syntax, as is using `A` and `B` as variables. In general, it is not clear what y9ou aim to do.

Comment: You don't want `zipWith` at the top level for that. Use `map` or some list comprehension like `[ zipWith (++) xs ["word", "other"] | xs <- .... ]`

Comment: @chi Thanks. Can you explain more? I am just learning Haskell.

Comment: @Zuckerbrenner: `'AA'` is not a valid string, and it can not be a character either. You canfurthermore not use it in `["AA" ..]` since a string is not an instance of `Enum`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem These were just examples but I didn't know that they wouldn't be considered valid, so thank you for the clarification. I am just trying to combine words from one string to the other but where all words of list b are applied to a. So if b was [["random", "random", "random"], ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs"], ["bacon", "bacon", "bacon"] and a was ["hello", "hi", "howdy"] it would return ["hellorandom", "hirandom", "howdyrandom"], ["helloeggs", "hieggs", "howdyeggs"]...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62923242/multiple-list-comprehension-haskell#comment111274216_62923242), the lists are for example:

```
b = [["random", "random", "random"], ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs"], ["bacon", "bacon", "bacon"]]
a = ["hello", "hi", "howdy"]
```

and you want to prepend the items in the sublists of `b` with the corresponding strings in `a`. We can do this with a combination of `map` and `zipWith`:

```
prepending :: [[a]] -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]
prepending = map . zipWith (++)
```

this is short for:

```
prepending :: [[a]] -> [[[a]]] -> [[[a]]]
prepending a b = map (zipWith (++) a) b
```

for example:

```
Prelude> prepending ["hello", "hi", "howdy"] [["random", "random", "random"], ["eggs", "eggs", "eggs"], ["bacon", "bacon", "bacon"]]
[["hellorandom","hirandom","howdyrandom"],["helloeggs","hieggs","howdyeggs"],["hellobacon","hibacon","howdybacon"]]
```

if `b` is however just a list of strings, like `["random", "eggs", "bacon"]`, you can make use of two maps:

```
prepending :: [[a]] -> [[a]] -> [[[a]]]
prepending a b = map ((`map` b) . (++)) a
```

this then produces:

```
Prelude> prepending ["hello", "hi", "howdy"] ["random", "eggs", "bacon"]
[["hellorandom","helloeggs","hellobacon"],["hirandom","hieggs","hibacon"],["howdyrandom","howdyeggs","howdybacon"]]
```

Comment: If we don't actually care about getting multiple lists out at the end (it's not really clear from the question), an even simpler approach is `prepending = liftA2 (++)`.